# $_FILES приходит пустой

Tags: php, ajax, fileupload

Проблема в заголовке.

Настройки php.ini

```
file_uploads On
max_file_uploads 192M
upload_max_filesize 192M
upload_tmp_dir /tmp
```

Форма:

```
<form action="#" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" type="hidden">

    <label>
        <span>Ваше имя</span>
        <input name="name" required="" type="text">
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Ваш телефон</span>
        <input name="phone" required="" type="text">
    </label>

    <label class="file-label">
        <span>Прикрепить файл</span>
        <input name="file" id="file" type="file">
    </label>

    <button class="btn">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("form.form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this),
        data = $(this).serialize(),
        url = 'mail.php';

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            dataType : "json"
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                console.log(msg);

                setTimeout(function(){
                    form.trigger("reset");
                }, 3000);

            });
        });
```

PHP:

```
$uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

Comment: а к чему `"form.form-file` вот это применяется?

Comment: Ошибся при копипасте.

Comment: хм..... ну ок...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, используйте **[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData)**

Вместо

```
data = $(this).serialize(),
```

будет

```
data = new FormData(this);
```

А еще бессмысленно писать `async: false,`. AJAX затем и делается, чтоб быть асинхронным

Comment: data = new FormData(this);
Приводит к ошибке